# How can I make these two spans stay on the same line, no matter how narrow the browser window gets?

Tags: html, css

I need two spans (in the example, checkboxyes and headlinecontents) to *always* stay in line horizontally with each other, no matter how narrow the browser window gets. I also need the checkboxyes span to float vertically, so that it is always centered with the current height of the headlinecontents span.

I have tried floating both as divs, which generally works for the "stay in line" requirement, but I can't seem to get the checkboxyes span to float vertically and stay centered on the headlinecontents span.

Here's the initial, very basic requirements. I've tried all kinds of float, display: inline-block, etc. combinations, with no luck.

```css
#container {
  width: 100%;
}

#checkboxyes {
  margin-right: 15px;
}

#checkbox {
  margin-right: 5px;
}

#yes {}

#headlinecontents {}

#headline {
  font-weight: bold;
}

#contents {}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <span id="checkboxyes">
          <span id="checkbox">checkbox</span>
  <span id="yes">YES</span>
  </span>
  <span id="headlinecontents">
          <div id="headline">Title of the article Title of the article </div>
          <div id="contents">Body of the article Body of the article Body of the article Body of the article Body of the article Body of the article Body of the article Body of the article Body of the article Body of the article Body of the article Body of the article Body of the article Body of the article </div>
       </span>
</div>
```

[image: Wide]

[image: Mid]

[image: Narrow]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
#checkboxyes {
  flex: 0;
  display: flex;
}
#headlinecontents {
  flex: 1;
}
```

See it working:

```css
#container {
  width: 100%;
}

#checkboxyes {
  margin-right: 15px;
}

#checkbox {
  margin-right: 5px;
}

#headlinecontents {}

#headline {
  font-weight: bold;
}

#container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

#checkboxyes {
  flex: 0;
  display: flex;
}

#headlinecontents {
  flex: 1;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <span id="checkboxyes">
      <span id="checkbox">checkbox</span>
  <span id="yes">YES</span>
  </span>
  <span id="headlinecontents">
      <div id="headline">Title of the article Title of the article </div>
      <div id="contents">Body of the article Body of the article Body of the article Body of the article Body of the article Body of the article Body of the article Body of the article Body of the article Body of the article Body of the article Body of the article Body of the article Body of the article </div>
   </span>
</div>
```

---

Useful resources:

- Official [flexbox documentation](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/).
- [Basic concepts of flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Basic_Concepts_of_Flexbox) on MDN
- CSS Trick's [Complete Guide to Flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/).

Comment: Fantastic, works great! Change flex: 0; to flex: 0 0 0; (which makes it work in IE11) and I'll accept as the correct answer.

Comment: My answer reflects the Standard Recommendation by W3C. Microsoft chose not to respect that standard on many accounts and their market share dropped below 2.5%, of which the vast majority are developers and website owners, still checking if their websites work in IE. I'm not changing my answer to include hacks for IE. Sorry to disappoint.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend using flexbox.

```
#container {
     display: flex;
}
```

Comment: And the flex-wrap property

Answer (score 0):

You can use flex-box. It is very easy to implement and can meet all your requirements. It is also responsive which is an important requirement for you as you had mentioned in your question.

https://jsfiddle.net/snehansh/6huvtxz2/7/

Assign `display: flex` to `<div id="container">`, using this you can specify alignments for its children, which are `checkboxyes` and `headlinecontents`. Note that by default flex-box aligns content horizontally, so you do not need to specify alignment for children.

```
  #container {
     width: 100%;
     display: flex;
  }
```

You want your span `checkboxyes` contents to aligned vertically-centered.

For this again, you will assign `display: flex` to the element `checkboxyes` and vertically align its children using `align-items: center;`.

```
  #checkboxyes {
     margin-right: 15px;
     display: flex;
     align-items: center;
  }
```

To read more about flex-box. You can refer: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/